# Processing a JSON response from TFL api using PHP?

Tags: php, json

I am trying to get certain information from the following JSON response from an API. This is the [actual API cal](https://api.tfl.gov.uk/Place?lat=51.555504&lon=0.0592359&radius=200&includeChildren=False&type=NaptanPublicBusCoachTram&app_id=&app_key=)l.

```js
{
  "$type": "Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.PlacesResponse, Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities",
  "centrePoint": [
    51.555,
    0.059
  ],
  "places": [{
    "$type": "Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.StopPoint, Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities",
    "naptanId": "490009219W",
    "indicator": "Stop B",
    "stopLetter": "B",
    "modes": [
      "bus"
    ],
    "icsCode": "1009219",
    "stopType": "NaptanPublicBusCoachTram",
    "stationNaptan": "490G00009219",
    "lines": [{
      "$type": "Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.Identifier, Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities",
      "id": "25",
      "name": "25",
      "uri": "/Line/25",
      "type": "Line"
    }, {
      "$type": "Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.Identifier, Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities",
      "id": "86",
      "name": "86",
      "uri": "/Line/86",
      "type": "Line"
    }, {
      "$type": "Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.Identifier, Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities",
      "id": "w19",
      "name": "W19",
      "uri": "/Line/w19",
      "type": "Line"
    }],
    "lineGroup": [{
      "$type": "Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.LineGroup, Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities",
      "naptanIdReference": "490009219W",
      "stationAtcoCode": "490G00009219",
      "lineIdentifier": [
        "25",
        "86",
        "w19"
      ]
    }],
    "lineModeGroups": [{
      "$type": "Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.LineModeGroup, Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities",
      "modeName": "bus",
      "lineIdentifier": [
        "25",
        "86",
        "w19"
      ]
    }],
    "status": true,
    "id": "490009219W",
    "commonName": "Little Ilford Lane",
    "distance": 64.10041498232529,
    "placeType": "StopPoint",
    "additionalProperties": [{
      "$type": "Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.AdditionalProperties, Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities",
      "category": "Direction",
      "key": "CompassPoint",
      "sourceSystemKey": "Naptan490",
      "value": "W"
    }, {
      "$type": "Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.AdditionalProperties, Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities",
      "category": "Direction",
      "key": "Towards",
      "sourceSystemKey": "CountDown",
      "value": "East Ham or Manor Park"
    }],
    "lat": 51.554475,
    "lon": 0.059381
  }]
}
```

I want to get the naptanId, line identifier and towards as name value pairs and print them. For example,

- naptan :490009219W;
- lineidentifer Whatever the values are
- towards :  "Eastham or manor park"

Please help me I am a beginner, 
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your question, it seems you are only interested in the values from the first `place` returned, so I'll assume that in the answer.

To get the data from the API into an object structure (as opposed to the JSON string you initially get):

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://api.tfl.gov.uk/Place?lat=51.555504&lon=0.0592359&radius=200&includeChildren=False&type=NaptanPublicBusCoachTram&app_id=&app_key='), true);
```

To get the `naptanId`:

```
$naptanId = $data['places'][0]['naptanId'];
```

To get the `lineIdentifier`, which I'll assume is the one from the first `lineGroup` element (not `lineModeGroups`, but you can change as appropriate):

```
$lineIdentifier = $data['places'][0]['lineGroup'][0]['lineIdentifier'];
```

This value will be an array.

To get the `towards` value is a bit more complex, because you need to filter the `additionalProperties` array based on a child key, then pull out the `value`; again I'm assuming you're only interested in the first value:

```
$towards = array_values(array_filter(
    $data['places'][0]['additionalProperties'], 
    function ($property) {
        return $property['key'] === 'Towards';
    }
))[0]['value'];
```

The call to `array_filter` pulls out the `additionalProperties` element where `key === 'Towards'` (note this assumes case sensitivity, you could add a `strtolower` and change the string literal to `'towards'` if you want to match case insensitively).  The call to `array_values` is necessary to normalise the array indexes.  Then we pull out the first element `[0]` and get its `value` property.

Note that the above code does not do any error checking, for example if the API call does not return any `places` then the first time you do `$data['places'][0]` it will fail.  If you need to handle these cases (which you almost certainly do), then you will need to pre-check these things, e.g.:

```
if (!isset($data['places']) || sizeof($data['places']) === 0) {...}
```